# US Median Household Income by Age and Cohort

Tags: demographics

I'm  looking for a dataset of US block-groups (or lowest available) that has household income by age bracket.  E.g. Age 35-50 Household Income, broken into monetary segments - 0-15k, etc.

Is this available in open form?  I'm aware of something pretty similar in the ESRI Business Analyst data, but wondered if there were an open source.

Comment: Try http://www.bls.gov/cps/ and similar surveys: take a sample, group by age, find the means.

Comment: According to the age/income of which person in the household? Or do you want *individual* income instead of household income?